# ¿Se puede conectar power BI a MYsql de manera remota?

Tags: mysql, powerbi

Buen dia

Quiero conectar powe bi a mi base de datos de manera remota NO local y poder manipular los datos a tiempo real pero desconozco si se puede

saludos

Comment: No es seguro que se pueda. Unos dicen que quizá sea posible mediante un túnel ssh. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44293564/5587982) y sus respuestas. [Es un reclamo que data ya de varios años](https://ideas.fabric.microsoft.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=1673aa83-99c0-4f2c-9e04-6eef0122aa2c), pero a Microsoft no parece interesarle demasiado.

Comment: La versión Desktop trae la conexión https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjRPh.png

Comment: tengo un compañero que ya lo pudo hacer te paso su correo por que e visto que muchas personas tienen ese problema 
genaro@misoftwaredigital.com